# How do I render validation errors in controller through twig template

Tags: php, symfony

How do I render validation errors in a controller through a twig template. I not able to access validation errors in the controller.

I found a way to do this

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($entity);
$content = $this->renderView('YourBundle:YourEntity:template.html.twig',array('errors'=>$errors));

{% if errors %}
    {% for error in errors %}
        <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

How do I get the field name which has the error out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($entity);
$content = $this->renderView('YourBundle:YourEntity:template.html.twig',array('errors'=>$errors));

{% if errors %}
    {% for error in errors %}
        <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        <li>{{ error.propertypath }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```